# Complicated positive series with a harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

$$\mathop{\LARGE\mathrm Σ}_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+1/2+...+1/n}{n}$$
Which are the terms of this sum? I wrote in a paper that the numerator has the terms:
$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...$
but I am not sure if this is correct because the series is not the same with:
$\mathop{\LARGE\mathrm Σ}_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.
There is also something else that bothers me,if the denominator is a sum that means you apply the formula for arithmetic progression:$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?
I do not understand how to solve this problem because the fraction gives me a lot of confusion.
I tried to solve it with the integral test but I got infinity/infinity(that's because I believed the nominator would be $\frac{1}{n}$ and all the terms added would result in a divergent series).
Can someone explain me?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  The series diverges since the $n$th term is greater than $1/n$ and the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: @saulspatz I am asking for the terms of this series. I do not fully understand why 1+1/2+...+1/n doesn't have the terms 1+1/2+1/3+1/4+...It's confusing because if I add 1+1/2+...+1/n I get a series like this:1+1+1\2+1\2+1\3+1\3+...

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n}$$ is obviously divergent, but $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n}$ can be easily computed by summation by parts.

Comment: How can you prove summation by parts with H(n)/n?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please,explain.

Comment: Just an idea to explore the field: perhaps there is something using $f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty H_k/k \cdot x^{k-1} $ and find what does $f(x)$ for small $x$ compute. For instance for $x=0.5$ this is convergent and gives $\zeta(2)$ (but I did not yet discover the general function)

Answer (score 1):

After Jack D'Aurizio's comment
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{H_n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(H_p\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}\psi ^{(1)}(p+1)+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$$ Using asymptotics
$$S_p=\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(p)+\gamma  \log (p)+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}+\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

As a test, $S_{10}=\frac{32160403}{6350400}\approx 5.06431$ while the above would give $4.96909$.

The relative error will be $\lt 0.1$% as soon as $p > 140$ and  $\lt 0.01$% as soon as $p > 1111.$

Answer (score 1):

Summation by parts gives that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n b_n = A_N b_N -\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A_n (b_{n+1}-b_n) $$
where $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$. In our case, picking $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=H_n$ we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n} &=& H_N^2 - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{H_n}{n(n+1)}=H_N^2-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{H_n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{H_{n}}{n+1}\\&=&H_N^2-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{H_n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\end{eqnarray*} $$
so
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n} = \frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\log^2N+\gamma\log(N)+\left(\frac{\gamma^2}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)+o(1). $$

Comment: Hmm, just an impulse: in the rhs of your last formula don't we have a simple quadratic form there? I think $\frac12 ((\log N+ \gamma)^2 + \zeta(2)) $

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: of course, I have just separated the terms according to their magnitude, so $\log^2(N)$ first, then $\log(N)$, then $O(1)$.

Comment: Well, I asked because $\log(N) + \gamma $ approximates $ H_N$ and is thus a meaningful -so to say- "special token" in this context of a formula involving of harmonic numbers and of its partial means... For $N \to \infty$ this would then suggest some formula like $\frac12\left(\zeta(1)^2 + \zeta(2)\right)$ and could give some suggestion towards more generalization?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: well, it is well-known that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n^s}$ (linear Euler sum) can be computed in terms of the values of the Riemann $\zeta$ function over $E=\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$, for any $s\in E$. The case presented by the OP is a limit case, related to the fact that $\zeta(s)$ has a simple pole with residue $1$ at $s=1$.

Comment: Jack - ah, thanks for this suggestion. I think I'll gather some more information about this next week and perhaps experiment with my software if time shall allow.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the convergence of the series the it is very easy: since

$$
a_n  = \frac{{1 + \frac{1}
{2} +  \cdots \frac{1}
{n}}}
{n} \geqslant \frac{1}
{n}
$$
for every n and since the series
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}
{n}} 
$$
your series is also divergent by direct comparison test.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: I can see how the series is solved in one series. It looks like this is a cauchy series. That means it diverges if it is bigger or equal than $$\ge \frac{1}{n}$$?

Comment: The comparison direct test that if a_n >= b_n >=0 and the series of b_n diverges them the series of a_n diverges also.

Answer (score 0):

The terms are $\frac 1 1=1$, $\frac {1+\frac 1 2} {2}=\frac 3  4$, $\frac {1+\frac  12 +\frac 1 3} {3}=\frac {11} {18}$, etc.